# SQLite + Trigger + Multiple Statements

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have a trigger setup as such:

- the first statement in the trigger increments a revision number
- the second statement in the trigger insert data into *another* table -- one item being the new revision number.

I'm noticing that that *new.revision* still reflects the old revision number (i.e. before the first statement's update). Does this mean, *new.revision* only reflects whatever value there was at event time, opposed to whatever the current value is after statement 1? Is there a quick way to query the current revision number for the affected row (i.e. after any changes from previous trigger statements)?

Comment: Please show the code.